# How to show logout link at the top right corner for non admin user

Tags: users

I want to show the logout link at top right of all pages, just like when we login as admin we could see logout link at the top right corner of the all pages, but problem is when I login as normal user [non admin] the logout link showing some where in the bottom, but I want to show it in the top right corner of all the pages please help me if anyone know!!

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to create a block to list all page. Then use code.

```
if (!in_array("administrator", $roles)) {
use logout link here(user/logout)...........
}
```

First you have to check whether the user is anonymous.

Comment: can you tell me where to keep this piece of code?

Comment: You have to create block in the top-region and put this code.